# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting - Counting In Reverse

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I have a simple Google Sheet. On this sheet I am tracking a small budget. This includes the following:

- Total budget
- Expenses (as line items)
- Total expenses
- Remaining budget

What I am trying to do is setup conditional formatting so that the cell holding the `Remaining budget` changes colors based on the total being displayed. That part is straight forward. The issue I am running into is that the `Remaining budget` is displaying the `Total budget` minus the `Total expenses`.

The conditional formatting is assuming that this number is counting up instead of down. When I put the formatting rules in, they are displaying in reverse of what I am wanting.

Is there a way to have the conditional formatting do what its doing based on the numbers subtracting rather than adding?

I did try looking for someone else with this same question, but I didn't see anything that quite fit my issue.

I have shared the Google Sheet at the following link and allowed Editor rights on this link. You can find the Google Sheet [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oqZXXLr8RE60StbOBJd7-5vZIVJLDCBiqVV5O1AhRd4/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: I'm sure everything you said in your post sounds "simple" and "straightforward" (and maybe it is). But that's only because you are looking at the sheet and data, and you already understand your own goal. From out here, it's a bit like you called the mechanic and said, "I can't bring car in for you to see it, but it's acting weird and going crch-crch-boing. What's wrong with it and how can I fix it?" The most efficient and effective way to get help will be to share a link to your sheet (or to a copy of it), being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, your main goal is to set the cell color to red when the budget left is zero, and change its color scale to green as the budget left increases.

You just need to change your Minpoint and Maxpoint number and color configuration.

[image]

As your budget runs out, it should change its color to red:

[image]

When your remaining budget is equal to your midpoint, it should change its color to yellow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See my added sheet, "Erik Help." All I did was swap the order of your numbers (0, 600, 601) and then click on both the red and the green paint cans for the top and bottom and swap those (i.e., red for green, green for red).

ADDENDUM: Looks like "Ron M" explained this for you. I've implemented that in my added sheet. Please mark Ron's reply post as "Best Answer," since it will help future site visitors most, based on the visuals.